# Organizar pastas, subpastas e aquivos de uma array?

Tags: php, array

Bom, eu tenho uma array com os valores:

```
array("Pasta/Readme.txt", "Pasta/Subpasta/helloworld.mp3", "Pasta-2/screenshot.png");
```

Como fazer para retornar uma array assim:

```
array("Pasta" => array("Readme.txt", "Subpasta" => array("helloworld.mp3")), "Pasta-2" => array("screenshot.png"))
```

Obrigado desde já :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que você sempre terá essa hierarquia: *m* pastas com *n* arquivos dentro de cada uma delas e nenhuma subpasta:

```
<?php

// vetor de arquivos
$arquivos = array(
    'Big Hero 6/Big Hero 6.avi',
    'Big Hero 6/readme.txt',
    'Big Hero 6 Screenshots/screenshot.png'
);

// vetor de arquivos divididos por pastas
$pastas = [];

// pegamos cada um dos arquivos e colocamos no array de subpastas,
// na pasta correspondente
for ($i=0, $count=sizeof($arquivos); $i<$count; $i++) {
    list($pasta, $arquivo) = explode('/', $arquivos[$i]);
    if (!isset($pastas[$pasta])) {
        $pastas[$pasta] = [];
    }
    $pastas[$pasta][] = $arquivo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para cada pasta, você pode rodar um scandir() para buscar seus arquivos

Veja http://php.net/scandir

Também é possível fazer isso com DirectoryIterator. Veja http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.directoryiterator.php